# DB2 creating temporal table creating column with CURRENT PACKAGESET or CLIENT_APPNAME

Tags: sql, database, db2

Does anyone know which of the DB2 special registers are allowed in CREATE TABLE statement for DB2 temporal tables or in general in CREATE TABLE statement?

I am trying to CREATE TABLE COLUMNS WITH CURRENT PACKAGESET or CLIENT_APPNAME, they are not being identified by DB2. I tried almost all combinations of key words (marked in bold).

Create table Statement

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
(EMP_NR INT NOT NULL
,FIRST_NAME CHAR(20) NOT NULL
,LAST_NAME CHAR(20) NOT NULL
,TSROWBEGIN TIMESTAMP(12) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW BEGIN    
,TSROWEND TIMESTAMP(12) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END     
,TSPGMSTART TIMESTAMP(12) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS TRANSACTION START ID

**,IDTERMANV CHAR(8) GENERATED DEFAULT WITH CURRENT PACKAGESET    
,IDTERM VARCHAR(128) GENERATED DEFAULT WITH CLIENT_APPLNAME**

,STDB2ACTION CHAR(1)  GENERATED ALWAYS AS  ( DATA CHANGE OPERATION )
,PERIOD SYSTEM_TIME(TSROWBEGIN, TSROWEND)  
);
```

It results in

> ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD CURRENT.  TOKEN  WAS EXPECTED. SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.68.61

or

> ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD CLIENT_APPLNAME.  TOKEN  WAS EXPECTED. SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.68.61

Any suggestions on how to create column with default value of program name which is doing CUD operation on the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the special registers for current date / time / timestamp and for user information (user, session user, system user). Take a look at the [CREATE TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html) reference.

The same reference also has a section about what cannot be used, in case you try to use a function or put the CREATE statement into a procedure. Among other things, the GENERATED value cannot be based on the following:

> Special registers and built-in functions that depend on the value of a special register.

Comment: Maybe I missed something while reading but I am not able to get what I am looking. Appreciate if you have any specific inputs. My need is to populate the program name with is updating or deleting the row from table automatically

Comment: my statement is that you cannot reference those special registers you need in a CREATE TABLE statement. What should work (IMHO) is to write an AFTER INSERT TRIGGER and update the inserted row with that value of CLIENT_APPLNAME